# preseed.cfg file for automatic installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, preseed

I already have a preseed.cfg for installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS like this :

```
    choose-mirror-bin mirror/http/proxy string
d-i base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-server
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i clock-setup/utc-auto boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i passwd/user-fullname string vagrant
d-i passwd/user-uid string 900
d-i passwd/user-password password vagrant
d-i passwd/user-password-again password vagrant
d-i passwd/username string vagrant
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server cryptsetup build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev linux-source dkms nfs-common
d-i pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select full-upgrade
d-i time/zone string UTC
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, ubuntu-server
```

But this file not run again with installation of Ubuntu 16 LTS. I don't understand and create this file alone. Can you help me to find a preseed.cfg file for the new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version please ?

**EDIT 1**

I try to create a preseed.cfg file with graphical tool : **system-config-kickstart**
but the file generated with this tool is not formatted like this up (with d-i in first of each line) and I already issue with this file. I'm blocking at selection language screen. Perhaps the issue is just this part of installation and not all the file. I investigued again...

**EDIT 2**

this is my boot command :

```
"boot_command": [
  "<esc><wait>",
  "<esc><wait>",
  "<enter><wait>",
  "/install/vmlinuz<wait>",
  " auto<wait>",
  " console-setup/ask_detect=false<wait>",
  " console-setup/layoutcode=fr<wait>",
  " console-setup/modelcode=pc105<wait>",
  " debconf/frontend=noninteractive<wait>",
  " debian-installer=fr_FR<wait>",
  " fb=false<wait>",
  " initrd=/install/initrd.gz<wait>",
  " kbd-chooser/method=fr<wait>",
  " keyboard-configuration/layout=fr<wait>",
  " keyboard-configuration/variant=fr<wait>",
  " locale=fr_FR<wait>",
  " netcfg/get_domain=vm<wait>",
  " netcfg/get_hostname=vagrant<wait>",
  " noapic<wait>",
  " preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed-16-1.cfg<wait>",
  " -- <wait>",
  "<enter><wait>"
],
```

Comment: Please edit your question. Add the information you're trying to automatic install Ubuntu with Packer. Mention it somewhere in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This preseed.cfg file work perfectly for me

```
choose-mirror-bin mirror/http/proxy string
d-i base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-server
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i clock-setup/utc-auto boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i passwd/user-fullname string vagrant
d-i passwd/user-uid string 900
d-i passwd/user-password password vagrant
d-i passwd/user-password-again password vagrant
d-i passwd/username string vagrant
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server cryptsetup build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev linux-source dkms nfs-common
d-i pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select full-upgrade
d-i time/zone string UTC
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, ubuntu-server
```

and the boot command for building VirtualBox with packer :

```
  "boot_command": [
    "<enter><wait><f6><esc><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
    "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
    "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
    "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
    "/install/vmlinuz<wait>",
    " auto<wait>",
    " console-setup/ask_detect=false<wait>",
    " console-setup/layoutcode=us<wait>",
    " console-setup/modelcode=pc105<wait>",
    " debconf/frontend=noninteractive<wait>",
    " debian-installer=en_US<wait>",
    " fb=false<wait>",
    " initrd=/install/initrd.gz<wait>",
    " kbd-chooser/method=us<wait>",
    " keyboard-configuration/layout=USA<wait>",
    " keyboard-configuration/variant=USA<wait>",
    " locale=en_US<wait>",
    " netcfg/get_domain=vm<wait>",
    " netcfg/get_hostname=vagrant<wait>",
    " grub-installer/bootdev=/dev/sda<wait>",
    " noapic<wait>",
    " preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg",
    " -- <wait>",
    "<enter><wait>"
  ],
```

This couple of code work perfectly for me with Packer > Vagrant > Virtualbox > windows 7. I tested for building a basic VM ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: I've always wanted to say this on an SE site: You don't need all that <bs>

;)

Comment: I was wrong. You can't see them but there are default options there that need to be deleted for a clean build.

Answer (score 0):

This method is not work for ubuntu 16.04:

```
"<esc><wait>",
"<esc><wait>",
"<enter><wait>",
```

I use

```
"<enter><wait><f6><esc><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>"
```

Comment: Please elaborate in which way this is providing an answer to the question.

Comment: Hi @KarlRichter, I agree with you the answer should be better elaborated. But the fact is, it does work and you will see the evidence if you put it in practice.

Comment: This seems to be a syslinux bug, [#823459](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=823459). It's fixed in [3:6.03+dfsg-14](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/syslinux/syslinux_6.03+dfsg-14/changelog) (yakkety)

Comment: @puetzk Wish I had seen your comment earlier. I was pulling my hair out wondering why my boot options weren't being recognized! I wish this change would be backported to 16.04 though.