# Command Line Install Doesn't Work in 16.04 mini.iso (Not ubuntu server)

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, iso, 32-bit, preseed

I'm currently running into an issue with creating a preseeded Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit install. I'm installing into a VirtualBox VM on an Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. The iso I'm using is here: [http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/)

My install prompt looks like this
[image]

And I can get to the boot prompt buy hitting `<esc>`.
[image]

I can also get to a different prompt (That already has a lot of text filled in) via selecting 
`Advanced options` -> `Command-line expert install` and hitting `<tab>` when `Command-line expert install` is selected
[image]

**The issue I'm currently having is that when I get to either command prompt, (clearing any text that may be there already) and try to load my preseed file, I am brought back to the first install screen (first image) or it continues to ask me questions, even though I have preseeded the answers. Then the process that waits for ssh to become available runs out of time and the process fails.**

```
==> virtualbox-iso: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> virtualbox-iso: Timeout waiting for SSH.
==> virtualbox-iso: Step "StepConnect" failed
==> virtualbox-iso: [c] Clean up and exit, [a] abort without cleanup, or [r] retry step
```

There are [some that claim this is a bug with Ubuntu that was not back-ported into 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761389/preseed-cfg-file-for-automatic-installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-lts#comment1304676_769545).

Currently, I see lots of help online for **Ubuntu server (not what I'm using)** and different key combos for the boot command to solve the problem.

I've tried:

1. Going to the first prompt and then adding the preseed file location 
   `"boot_command": [
       "<esc><wait>",
       "/install/vmlinuz <wait>",
       "auto=true <wait>",
       "priority=critical <wait>", 
       "url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed_{{user`ubuntu_name`}}.cfg <wait>",
       "preseed/interactive=false <wait>",
       "<enter><wait>"
     ],`
2. Going to the second prompt and giving the preseed file location
   `"boot_command": [
       "<down><down><enter><down><down><tab>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
       "/install/vmlinuz <wait>",
       "auto=true <wait>",
       "priority=critical <wait>", 
       "url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed_{{user`ubuntu_name`}}.cfg <wait>",
       "preseed/interactive=false <wait>",
       "<enter><wait>"
     ],`
3. Going to the first (and second) prompt and then adding the preseed file location *using a different install keyword*
   `"boot_command": [
       "<esc><wait>",
       "install <wait>",
       "auto <wait>",
       "priority=critical <wait>", 
       "url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed_{{user`ubuntu_name`}}.cfg <wait>",
       "preseed/interactive=false <wait>",
       "<enter><wait>"
     ],`
4. Going to the first (and second) prompt and then adding the preseed file location *using a different preseed url keyword*
   `"boot_command": [
       "<esc><wait>",
       "/install/vmlinuz <wait>",
       "auto <wait>",
       "priority=critical <wait>", 
       "preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed_{{user`ubuntu_name`}}.cfg <wait>",
       "preseed/interactive=false <wait>",
       "<enter><wait>"
     ],`
5. Going to the first (and second) prompt and then adding the preseed file location *using extended keywords*
   `"boot_command": [
       "<esc><wait>",
       "/install/vmlinuz <wait>",
       "auto <wait>",
       "priority=critical <wait>", 
       "preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed_{{user`ubuntu_name`}}.cfg <wait>",
       "preseed/interactive=false <wait>",
       "debian-installer=en_US <wait>",
       "locale=en_US <wait>",
       "kbd-chooser/method=dk <wait>",
       "keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap=dk <wait>",
       "netcfg/get_hostname={{ .Name }} <wait>",
       "netcfg/get_domain=vagrantup.com <wait>",
       "fb=false <wait>",
       "debconf/frontend=noninteractive <wait>",
       "console-setup/ask_detect=false <wait>",
       "console-keymaps-at/keymap=dk <wait>",
       "<enter><wait>"
     ],`
6. I've tried using a different iso (tried to get the ubuntu server iso) but when I do, the virtuabox process can't make a hardrive for it.

```
    ==> virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying ISO
    ==> virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-server-i386.iso
    ==> virtualbox-iso: Starting HTTP server on port 8916
    ==> virtualbox-iso: Creating virtual machine...
    ==> virtualbox-iso: Creating hard drive...
    ==> virtualbox-iso: Error attaching ISO: VBoxManage error: VBoxManage: error: Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/project/packer_cache/414469dcbe8946731d7d3f214d3dd31de5806cb67eabc1873b915662bd2ba4cd.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
    ==> virtualbox-iso: VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
    ==> virtualbox-iso: VBoxManage: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 179 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
    ==> virtualbox-iso: VBoxManage: error: Invalid UUID or filename "/home/project/packer_cache/414469dcbe8946731d7d3f214d3dd31de5806cb67eabc1873b915662bd2ba4cd.iso"
    ==> virtualbox-iso: Step "stepAttachISO" failed
    ==> virtualbox-iso: [c] Clean up and exit, [a] abort without cleanup, or [r] retry step (build may fail even if retry succ
    ceeds)? ==> virtualbox-iso: Unregistering and deleting virtual machine...
    ==> virtualbox-iso: Deleting output directory...
    Build 'virtualbox-iso' errored: Error attaching ISO: VBoxManage error: VBoxManage: error: Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/project/packer_cache/414469dcbe8946731d7d3f214d3dd31de5806cb67eabc1873b915662bd2ba4cd.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
    VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
    VBoxManage: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 179 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
    VBoxManage: error: Invalid UUID or filename "/home/project/packer_cache/414469dcbe8946731d7d3f214d3dd31de5806cb67eabc1873b915662bd2ba4cd.iso"
```

My preseed file (`preseed_xenial.cfg`):

```
### Unattended Installation
d-i auto-install/enable boolean true
d-i debconf/priority select critical

### Localization
# Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_DK.UTF-8

# The values can also be preseeded individually for greater flexibility.
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string DK
# Optionally specify additional locales to be generated.
d-i localechooser/supported-locales multiselect en_DK.UTF-8, en_US.UTF-8, da_DK.UTF-8

# Keyboard selection.
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select dk

### Network configuration
# netcfg will choose an interface that has link if possible. This makes it
# skip displaying a list if there is more than one interface.
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

# Any hostname and domain names assigned from dhcp take precedence over
# values set here. However, setting the values still prevents the questions
# from being shown, even if values come from dhcp.
d-i netcfg/hostname string ur

### Mirror settings
# If you select ftp, the mirror/country string does not need to be set.
d-i mirror/protocol string ftp
d-i mirror/ftp/hostname string ftp.de.ubuntu.org
d-i mirror/ftp/directory string /ubuntu
d-i mirror/ftp/proxy string

### Account setup
# Skip creation of a root account (normal user account will be able to
# use sudo). The default is false; preseed this to true if you want to set
# a root password.
d-i passwd/root-login boolean false

d-i passwd/root-password-again password vagrant
d-i passwd/user-fullname string vagrant
d-i passwd/user-uid string 900
d-i passwd/user-password password vagrant
d-i passwd/user-password-again password vagrant
d-i passwd/username string vagrant
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false

### Clock and time zone setup
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string EU/Copenhagen
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true

### Partitioning
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
# - regular: use the usual partition types for your architecture
# - lvm:     use LVM to partition the disk
# - crypto:  use LVM within an encrypted partition
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
#d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
  all-in-one :: \
    50 50 50 ext3 \
      $primary{ } \
      $bootable{ } \
      method{ format } format{ } \
      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 } \
      mountpoint{ /boot/grub } \
      . \
    250 250 250 ext3 \
      $primary{ } \
      method{ format } format{ } \
      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 } \
      mountpoint{ /tmp } \
      . \
    2000 2000 2000 ext3 \
      $primary{ } \
      method{ format } \
      format{ } \
      use_filesystem{ } \
      filesystem{ ext3 } \
      mountpoint{ / } . \
    50 1000 -1 ext3 \
      $primary{ } \
      method{ format } format{ } \
      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext3 } \
      mountpoint{ /data } \
      . \
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select all-in-one
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/mount_style select uuid
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string /dev/sda


###################################
### Kernel installation
d-i base-installer/kernel/image string linux-image-686-pae
###################################

### Apt
d-i apt-setup/non-free boolean false
d-i apt-setup/contrib boolean false
d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect security
d-i apt-setup/security_host string security.ubuntu.org

### Package selection
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server sudo bzip2 acpid zlib1g-dev wget curl dkms make
# No language support packages.
d-i pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select none
# Prevent packaged version of VirtualBox Guest Additions being installed:
d-i preseed/early_command string sed -i \
  '/in-target/idiscover(){/sbin/discover|grep -v VirtualBox;}' \
  /usr/lib/pre-pkgsel.d/20install-hwpackages
popularity-contest popularity-contest/participate boolean false

### Other
# Allow non-free firmware
d-i hw-detect/load_firmware boolean true
# Avoid that last message about the install being complete.
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

My packer template file (`ubutntu_xenial`):

```
    {
    "variables": {
        "ubuntu_version": "16.04",
        "ubuntu_name": "xenial"
    },
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "virtualbox-iso",
      "boot_command": [
        "<esc><wait>",
        "/install/vmlinuz <wait>",
        "auto=true <wait>",
        "priority=critical <wait>", 
        "url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed_{{user `ubuntu_name`}}.cfg <wait>",
        "preseed/interactive=false <wait>",
        "<enter><wait>"
      ],
      "boot_wait": "5s",
      "disk_size": 2700,
      "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu",
      "headless": false,
      "http_directory": "http",
      "iso_url": "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/{{user `ubuntu_name`}}-updates/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso",
      "iso_checksum_type": "none",
      "ssh_username": "vagrant",
      "ssh_password": "vagrant",
      "ssh_port": 22,
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "1000s",
      "shutdown_command": "echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S /sbin/shutdown -hP now",
      "guest_additions_path": "VBoxGuestAdditions_{{.Version}}.iso",
      "virtualbox_version_file": ".vbox_version",
      "vm_name": "ubuntu-{{user `ubuntu_version`}}-i386",
      "vboxmanage": [
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--memory", "4096" ],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--cpus", "4" ],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--vram", "128"],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--usb", "off"],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--ostype", "Ubuntu"],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--acpi", "on"],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--ioapic", "on"],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--hwvirtex", "on"],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--pae", "on"],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--nestedpaging", "on"],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--rtcuseutc", "on"],
        [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--vrde", "on"]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "post-processors": [
    {
      "type": "vagrant",
      "compression_level": "9",
      "output": "ubuntu-{{user `ubuntu_version`}}-i386_{{.Provider}}.box",
      "only": ["virtualbox-iso"]
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "scripts/expand-rootfs.sh",
      "destination": "/home/vagrant/expand-rootfs.sh"
    },
    {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "scripts/regen-ssh-keys.sh",
      "destination": "/home/vagrant/regen-ssh-keys.sh"
    },
    {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "scripts/on-first-boot.sh",
      "destination": "/home/vagrant/on-first-boot.sh"
    },
    {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "scripts/on-first-boot.service",
      "destination": "/home/vagrant/on-first-boot.service"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "execute_command": "echo 'vagrant' | {{.Vars}} sudo -E -S bash '{{.Path}}'",
      "scripts": [
        "scripts/update.sh",
        "scripts/fs.sh",
        "scripts/sshd.sh",
        "scripts/networking.sh",
        "scripts/sudoers.sh",
        "scripts/vagrant.sh",
        "scripts/vbaddguest.sh",
        "scripts/cleanup.sh"
      ],
      "only": ["virtualbox-iso"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure why it's not working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
"<tab><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
"<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
"<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
"<wait> preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/ubuntu-server.seed ",
"debian-installer=en_US auto=true locale=en_US kbd-chooser/method=us ",
"console-setup/ask_detect=false keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us ",
"hostname=ubuntu initrd=initrd.gz --- quiet <wait><enter>"
```

Comment: It is better to include a brief description of what your fix is doing, not just posting the raw code. 'Teach a man to fish' philosophy.